# In Azure, What is the difference between wwwroot and repository?

Tags: node.js, azure

I recently started to make my website and found interesting thing. I spent like 30 mins to modify my index page but it didn't change somehow. And then I found out index.jade is the one in wwwroot folder, not repository folder. I compared these two folders and it has no difference at all. They both have same jade files.

I wonder what is the purpose for each directory? What wwwroot directory for and what repository directory for?

When I tested, there is no change in "actual website" when I modify index.jade file in repository directory. But actual website changes when I modify index.jade file in wwwroot folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GopiKolla's answer is mostly right. Additionally, you can install Azure-cli, and run command `azure site deploymentscript --node` to generate a `deploymentscript` for node.js, then you can find all commands the Azure deployment task will execute in `deploy.cmd` during the deployment. You could have a further insight about the directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provision a webapp in Azure appservice you will not have repository folder by default. When you enable deployments (like say Local Git Repository) then repository folder is created. wwwroot will be there by default and is the right location where the actual content is served by the webapp. Repository is where you can push your code (through git push) from local git repo to azure remote and will be first staged in "repository" directory and deployed to "wwwroot" but i don't think if you change/upload/ftp the files to repository it won't impact anything unless you either copy to wwwroot as well (or deploy code through git push to remote). so in short wwwroot is where the content is served by your web server and repository is where the code is managed/staged for fetch/push.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-deploy-local-git/